# 'I'm going into the city' vs. 'I'm going to the city'

Tags: prepositions

Suppose a person is relatively close to Los Angeles, say one mile, could they say 'I'm going *into* the city'? If yes, suppose that that person is 50 miles from Los Angeles, could they say 'I'm going *to* the city'? If yes, suppose the person is moving toward Los Angeles, what is the distance from that city at which that person should replace 'to' with 'into'? 10 miles, 5 miles, or less?

Also, could that distance depend on how big is the city to which that person is arriving?

Comment: I don't think it depends on distance per se, but on the attractions, sites, and bustling parts of each city that give the locals pride and identity. In the U.S., Las Vegas has "the Strip", New Orleans has Bourbon Street and the French Quarter, Boston has its Freedom Trail, and Washington D.C. has "the Mall." You go _into_ the city to get to those places. My tongue-in-cheek definition? When you know it's going to be difficult (if not nearly impossible) to park your car, then you're definitely going _into_ the city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be ridiculous to suppose there's some kind of "critical distance" involved here, whereby people nearer would always speak of going *into* the city, and people further away would simply go *to* the city.

It's just that *into* more strongly implies going *right inside* the place (usually, the city or town *centre*, in this case). It's a metaphor of *location*, invariably implying a *central part* of the stated destination.

Going *to* a place is a metaphor of *direction (to = towards, in the direction of)*. If you're going *to London*, your intended destination is indeed some part of London, but it might not be a particularly central part.

I live less than 1/2 a mile from my local town centre, but it's a fairly large town, and even in the opposite direction people well over a mile away are still considered to live *in* this town. And we all speak of going *into* town when we mean going to the town centre.

Los Angeles is famously "spread out" (the area is almost as big as London, but the population is less than half). People living in outer parts of London commonly speak of going *into London* to mean *going to a much more central part*, and I expect Angelenos would be at least as likely to adopt such usages.

---

So the short answer is you go *to* a place that's somewhere other than where you started (the preposition represents the *direction* you'll be going in). You go *into* a place when your destination is somewhere that could reasonably be described as "inside" that place (the preposition represents your spatial location).

Comment: You're correct; over here, going _into_ San Antonio would likely mean going near the center of town (probably very near the Riverwalk), while going _to_ San Antonio wouldn't preclude that, but it might just as easily mean any suburb within a reasonable distance from San Antonio.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary contains this definition for the preposition "into":

2. toward or in the direction of: **going into town.**

also to I know that "**to more important place**" is:

to a more important place: up to London.(Collins English Dictionary)

although I only can provide dictionary definitions and you have to rely on them solely as English is my second language.